# unexpected output when calculating the mean of dataset using tensorflow's mean function

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to calculate the mean  of a dataset using tensorflow

```
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("My_file.csv", delimiter = ';') 
Y = dataset[100:151,1]
Mean = tf.reduce_mean(f.convert_to_tensor(Y, numpy.float32), axis = -1)
```

But I am getting this output error

```
Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Is there any clue what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: That is not an error, this is the description of Mean: a tensor of shape () -i.e. a scalar- of type float32. If you want its value, try `Sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` and then `print(Mean.eval())`.

Comment: @gdelab Yes, this is ; it seems that such calculations on  tensorflow should be done inside sessions. Thanks

Comment: The problem resides when I use it in a function: `def r2(y_true, y_pred):  
    S1 = k.sum(k.square(y_pred - k.mean(y_true, axis = -1), axis = -1))
    S2 = k.sum(k.square(y_true - k.mean(y_true, axis = -1),  axis = -1))
    return S1/S2  print(r2(Y, P))`